# What does LOCAL_CFLAGS -mno-thumb means?

Tags: android-ndk

I Know that LOCAL_CFLAGS are an optional set of compiler flags that will be passed when building C source files. My question is what this flags means "-mno-thumb" or where can i find a list of avaible LOCAL_CFLAGS and their menanings.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 5):

The `LOCAL_CFLAGS` options are, in an `Android.mk` file, equivalent to the usual [CFLAGS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFLAGS) normally used with the compiler to specify compiling options.

There are *tons* of such options, the documentation for most of them can be found for example in the various links on [this page from the GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC).

As for the `-mno-thumb` option, it deactivates the [Thumb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Thumb) optional instruction set available on most (recent) ARM processors. This instruction set is a limited, <strike>faster</strike> slower (EDIT: see answer by whobertoos)  instruction set than the usual ARM instructions, so disabling it using this flag ensures a compatibility with more (mainly older) processors, but will probably cost you performance as a counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

mbrenon is right in almost everything he wrote.
However the THUMB instruction set is slower than ARM instructions set. It takes less space but it is slower.

How is that. 
Each thumb instruction occupies half of space comparing to arm instruction. This limits the options available for each instruction e.g. parameters, addressing modes etc. This results in more instructions needed to perform the same job and each instruction requires one execution cycle hence the slowdown. 
It is estimated that program in ARM mode is 30-40% faster but program in THUMB mode takes 30-40% less space. Thumb was invented for memory limited systems.

Thumb mode also impacts the external memory power.

Although there are more instructions which need to be executed in most cases two instructions can be fetched in one cycle. This is my understanding of the issue. I am not 100% sure if that is complete answer.